# Material-Table PDF export - strange characters

Tags: material-table

When exporting data from material-table some rows have "strange" characters.
Anyone know what might be causing this?

[cropped area showing sample of report section with strange characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qblNa.jpg)

Any help would be appreciated.